# Select dataframe rows defining a date range that contains a needle date

Tags: python, pandas

There are lots of answers which make it easy to select some date range and get the ones that fall into that range.

I don't want that.

I have data like this:

```
     id  other_flags   d_dt_start    d_dt_end
0    28          ...   1993-02-12  1993-12-31
1    28          ...   1993-02-12  1993-12-31
2    46          ...   1986-01-15  1993-09-30
3    46          ...   1986-01-15  1993-09-30
4    46          ...   1986-01-15  1993-09-30
```

I want to select the ones that match when I have a date, say, `1986-06-15`, thus giving me the subset of indices 2, 3, and 4. Currently, I'm doing this by something like this:

```
subs = subs[(time >= subs['d_dt_start1'])   # later
            & (time <= subs['d_dt_end1'])]  # before
```

There has got to be a more elegant way to do this similar to the `between` command, just the opposite of that.

Basically, instead of saying 'you have a date, I have a date range', 'you have a date range, I have a date'.

Comment: But the df doesn't have a range, it has two dates. There's nothing wrong with your current logic and almost nothing to be gained. If you really want, make if a function and use `subs.apply`

Comment: Seems pretty elegant to me You want to see if a date falls between values in 2 different columns so you do two comparisons, one with each column. Is there really anything simpler?

Comment: So if I want to merge on a ‘matches the date range’ column, the I would have to create the column and merge based on that column?

Comment: Your logic is correct, elegant and please dont use `apply`

Comment: Ah, so you ultimately want to merge two `DataFrames`, but the condition is if the date in one falls between the date range in another? I think that's a difficult problem. Perhaps two uses of `pandas.merge_asof()`?

Comment: Why not use apply?

Comment: Is there something like R's `%between%`?